# Indicating which branches track which remote branches

Tags: git

This is my understanding of Git:-

If I clone a repository then I initially only get a copy of the master branch. I can then indicate that I want to track a remote branch using `git checkout` with the `-b` flag. This works as expected.

So my question is how do you get Git to tell you this information. If I type `git branch -a` then it shows me a mixed list of all the branches e.g.

```
* master
  mybranch
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/mybranch
```

What I want to know is other than maintaining the same name, how can I tell what local branches are tracking what remote ones?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I clone a repository then I initially only get a copy of the master branch. I can then indicate that I want to track a remote branch using git checkout with the -b flag. This works as expected.

In fact, `git checkout -b ...` is what you use to create a *new* branch.  If you simply want to check out a branch that already exists in the remote, you don't need `-b`.  For example, here I'm creating a local branch that tracks `remotes/origin/folder-hack`:

```
$ git checkout folder-hack
Branch folder-hack set up to track remote branch folder-hack from amdragon.
Switched to a new branch 'folder-hack'
```

> What I want to know is other than maintaining the same name, how can I tell what local branches are tracking what remote ones?

Each branch has a corresponding configuration in `.git/config`.  You can find the *remote* associated with a branch by looking at `branch.<BRANCHNAME>.remote`, and you can find the name of the remote branch by looking at `branch.<BRANCHNAME>.merge`.  So, from my previous example:

```
$ git config --get branch.folder-hack.remote
amdragon
$ git config --get branch.folder-hack.merge
refs/heads/folder-hack
```

You can just run `git config --list` and look at the `branch...` lines.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
git branch -vv
```

The remote branch is displayed on the same line as the local branch that's tracking it.

Answer (score 0):

You can see all the remote's branches and which local branches already track the remote with:

```
git remote show origin
```